# What is the probability of at least one event among a set of independent or mutually exclusive events?

Tags: probability

I have a series of events, each with its own probability $P(A)$, $P(B)$, $P(C)$.

As a first case, let's consider them independent from each other. In this case, I know that the probability of two of them occurring is $P(A \text{ and } B) = P(A)P(B)$ etc., while the probability of at least one of them occurring is the same as the probability of either of them occurring, that is:

$P(A \text{ or } B \text{ or } C) = P(A) + P(B) + P(C) - P(A \text{ and } B) - P(A \text{ and } C) - P(B \text{ and } C) + P(A \text{ and } B \text{ and } C)$

which is actually equivalent to $1 - (1-P(A))(1-P(B))(1-P(C))$.

However, let's consider a second case where the same events are mutually exclusive, meaning that $P(A \text{ and } B) = 0$ etc., implying that

$P(A \text{ or } B \text{ or } C) = P(A) + P(B) + P(C)$

Here is where my confusion arises. As far as I know, "mutually exclusive" doesn't mean complementary, meaning that the sum of their probabilities doesn't automatically equal 1.

- Could this sum become larger than 1 if the probabilities are large enough?
- Is the probability of at least one occurring still $1 - (1-P(A))(1-P(B))(1-P(C))$ ?

What am I missing?

Comment: But if A,B and C are independent of each other then how can it be that they are exclusive of each other (indicating a relation between A, B and C) . Also, P(A and  B) is never 0 unless either P(A) or P(B) is 0.

Comment: If A, B and C are just mutually exclusive then yeah, P(A) + P(B) + P(C) $\le$ 1.

Comment: "*Is the probability of at least one still $1-(1-P(A))(1-P(B))(1-P(C))$?  No.  That was specifically for independent events, not for mutually exclusive.

Comment: @Aadi Maybe I explained myself badly, there are two different problems, one where the events are independent, and one where they are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Easiest to first examine the situation with two mutually exclusive events.  In general, for **any two events**, $A$ and $B$, regardless of whether they are mutually exclusive, and regardless of whether they are independent of each other, you have the (Venn Diagram motivated) formula of $$P(A \cup B) = p(A) + p(B) - p(A \cap B).$$  When $A,B$ are mutually exclusive, then $p(A \cap B) = 0.$

Comment: "*What am I missing?*"  I don't know what you mean by this.  Everything you wrote that you stated you believed as fact is correct.  You posed some questions at the end which you have not stated whether you believe are true or not.  The answer to both is "no" and should be clear why, either from definitions or by basic examples.  The sum can not be larger than one because the sum represents a single probability, and all probabilities are less than or equal to $1$.  The probability of at least one is not as you show, exampled by a single coin toss, the first event being 'H' and second 'T'

Comment: The expression $1-(1-P(A))(1-P(B))$ and related can be explained *for independent events* because if $A,B$ are independent then so too are the other combinations of $A$ and $B$ or their complements, namely $(A,B^c)$ or $(A^c,B)$ or $(A^c,B^c)$.  Couple that with DeMorgan's laws that $P(A\cup B)=P((A^c\cap B^c)^c) = 1 - P(A^c\cap B^c)$

Comment: @JMoravitz thanks, maybe I should have phrased my question better. Then, in the mutually exclusive case, what is the probability of at least one event?

Comment: $P(A)+P(B)+P(C)$ and there is little more that is useful that can be said without more details

Comment: Re my last comment, when $A$ and $B$ are **not** mutually exclusive, then $p(A \cap B) \neq 0.$  In that situation, the correct way of computing $p(A \cap B)$ will **depend** on whether $A,B$ are independent events.  That is, if independent, then $$p(A \cap B) = p(A) \times p(B).$$  If not independent, then $$p(A \cap B) = p(A) \times p(B|A),$$ where the second factor above represents the probability that event $B$ occurred, **under the assumption** that event $A$ **did occur**.